# MS-DOS 6.22 keyboard configuration

Tags: keyboard, microsoft-virtual-pc, ms-dos, windows-3.1

I have MS-DOS 6.22 in a virtual machine (Virtual PC 2007) and I wanted to properly configure the keyboard.

The keyboard I have is a French-Canadian one (FYI in Windows XP my keyboard is labeled "Français (Canada) - Français (Canada)" in the control pannel).

What do I need to put in autoexec.bat and config.sys in order to use the keyboard properly (Windows 3.11 will be installed later if it matters)?

I haven't configured DOS since like 14 years so all my references are lost/trashed now :)

Comment: That's fantastic. What is this for? Old games?

Comment: Nah i'm just nostalgic. I'm resinstalling those old OSes to see how bad has become what was hot at at that time :) And to see the evolution curve and also be able to show "younger" people how it was before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the try but found it in a [dusty Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/462967/fr) :)

**Canada (English)**

Config.sys :

```
Country=004,850,c:\dos\country.sys
Device=c:\dos\display.sys con=(ega,850,2)
```

Autoexec.bat :

```
Mode con cp prep=((850 863) c:\dos\ega.cpi)
Mode con cp select=850
Keyb cf,850,c:\dos\keybrd2.sys
```

**Canada (français) (French)**

Config.sys :

```
Country=002,850,c:\dos\country.sys
Device=c:\dos\display.sys con=(ega,850,2)
```

Autoexec.bat :

```
Mode con cp prep=((850 863) c:\dos\ega.cpi)
Mode con cp select=850
Keyb cf,850,c:\dos\keyboard.sys
```

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't it something like this in autoexec.bat? Be sure to check the real codepages and keyb variables.

```
mode con codepage select=850
keyb fr,,c:\dos\keyboard.sys
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but there are steps provided in [this forum thread](http://www.techtalkz.com/windows-vista-all/22022-keyboard-layout-under-command-prompt.html). I'm still looking for more info.