# How to enable Alt Gr or Alt keys on a Telnet Server

Tags: keyboard, putty, telnet

I'm running a telnet server `KpyM` on a **Windows Server 2008**. My telnet client is a `Putty` on my **Windows 10** computer.

I'm running a 16-bit DOS Application through telnet.

I need to use the `"\"` on an `AZERTY keyboard`. There are two ways to have it : `Alt Gr + 8`  or `Alt + 92`.

**Here is what I have:**

[image]

**Here is what I want:**

[image]

This depends on my telnet server, for example when I use the Telnet Server from Windows, it gives me `"_ _ _ _ "`

How to fix this? 
On my KTS folder, there are some interesting files like : 
`utf-8.ini`  `telnet.ini` `kts.ini`

---

**EDIT:**

Referring to this post : [MS-DOS 6.22 keyboard configuration](https://superuser.com/questions/138339/ms-dos-6-22-keyboard-configuration?rq=1)

I've changed my autoexec.nt file and config.nt , but Alt Gr + 8 is still non-existant.
Indeed, it sets the keyboard in FR as I want.

- autoexec.nt :

```
Mode con cp prep=((850 863) C:\Windows\System32\ega.cpi)
Mode con cp select=850
KB16 fr,850,C:\Windows\System32\keyboard.sys
```

- config.nt :

```
dos=high, umb
Country=002,850,C:\Windows\System32\country.sys
device=%SystemRoot%\system32\display.sys con=(ega,850,2)
files=40
```

Comment: No one has an idea on this?

Comment: Where can I find the config files for windows 10 keyboard?

Comment: Does this happen with EDIT.COM? Does this happen with non-16bit programs?

Comment: How can I see this? I can't open from telnet a non-16bit program, it does nothing.
All I can say is that it is related to COMMAND.COM, and when I'm on telnet, the Alt Gr works fine, but from the moment I run my app, impossible. You can refer to my other question here :
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57060461/telnet-client-switching-from-cmd-exe-to-command-com

Comment: Post edited with MS DOS Keyboard config